# Crash Dump debugging with windbg. Could not conclude crash is due to app or JIT

Tags: c#

Hello Application is written in c#. Crash is happening in production environment. If analyzed the crash using windbg I am not able to come to conclusion.  I don't have some of third party pdb files. How to read this below dump analyze output and where is the problem? Is the application causing crash or just-in-debugeer causing the crash?

#Below is the Dump Output#

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.11.0001.404 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [D:\pratheep\PED\CXM\CrashDebug\BIB\VoiceInterfaceControllerBIB\bin\VoiceInterfaceControllerBIB.exe.9652.dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Symbol search path is: D:\pratheep\PED\CXM\CrashDebug\BIB\VoiceInterfaceControllerBIB\bin;E:\csharpcache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols
Executable search path is: D:\pratheep\PED\CXM\CrashDebug\BIB\VoiceInterfaceControllerBIB\bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (16 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Thu Mar 10 01:33:53.000 2016 (GMT+5)
System Uptime: 10 days 2:49:21.464
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:46:45.000
................................................................
...........
Loading unloaded module list
................................................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(25b4.744): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa:
00000000`7706d96a c3              ret
0:143> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for VoiceInterfaceControllerBIB.exe
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for LumiSoft.Net.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for log4net.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for CcmProfiler.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ccmcore.dll - 
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Core.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Xml.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for System.Xml.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for perfcounter.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for CcmSqlCE.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for aspnet_counters.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for mscoreei.dll - 
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Configuration.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for System.Configuration.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ServiceProcess.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for System.ServiceProcess.ni.dll
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Your debugger is not using the correct symbols                 ***
***                                                                   ***
***    In order for this command to work properly, your symbol path   ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: kernel32!pNlsUserInfo                         ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Your debugger is not using the correct symbols                 ***
***                                                                   ***
***    In order for this command to work properly, your symbol path   ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: kernel32!pNlsUserInfo                         ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
000007ff`001fc6e1 803e00          cmp     byte ptr [rsi],0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  000000002750bce0 -- (.exr 0x2750bce0)
ExceptionAddress: 000007fefd05965d (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x0000000000000039)
   ExceptionCode: e0434f4d (CLR exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000022
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: ffffffff80131622

PROCESS_NAME:  VoiceInterfaceControllerBIB.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000000

READ_ADDRESS:  0000000000000000 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
mscorwks!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+2ff
000007fe`f936b943 90              nop

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
+2ff
000007ff`001fc6e1 803e00          cmp     byte ptr [rsi],0

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

MANAGED_STACK: 
SP               IP               Function
    000000002750A060 000007FF001FC6E1 LumiSoft_Net!LumiSoft.Net.RTP.RTP_Session.RtpIOCompletionReceive(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs)+0x1a1
    000000002750E430 000007FEEDCED58E System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs)+0x1e
    000000002750E460 000007FEF82DDD38 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)+0x178
    000000002750ED00 0000000000000001 mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)+0x2
    000000002750ED00 000007FEF82C2B82 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x62
    000000002750ED50 000007FEEDCEEBBF System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)+0xa9f
    000000002750EE90 000007FEEDCED8CE System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x3e
    000000002750EEE0 000007FEF82FA91E mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0xce

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80004003
There are nested exceptions on this thread. Run with -nested for details

EXCEPTION_OBJECT: !pe 2240580
Exception object: 0000000002240580
Exception type: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000002750A060 000007FF001FC6E1 LumiSoft_Net!LumiSoft.Net.RTP.RTP_Session.RtpIOCompletionReceive(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs)+0x1a1
    000000002750E430 000007FEEDCED58E System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs)+0x1e
    000000002750E460 000007FEF82DDD38 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)+0x178
    000000002750ED00 0000000000000001 mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)+0x2
    000000002750ED00 000007FEF82C2B82 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x62
    000000002750ED50 000007FEEDCEEBBF System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)+0xa9f
    000000002750EE90 000007FEEDCED8CE System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x3e
    000000002750EEE0 000007FEF82FA91E mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0xce

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80004003
There are nested exceptions on this thread. Run with -nested for details

MANAGED_OBJECT: !dumpobj 14cba90
Name: System.String
MethodTable: 000007fef8407d90
EEClass: 000007fef800e560
Size: 132(0x84) bytes
 (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
String: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fef840f000  4000096        8         System.Int32  1 instance               54 m_arrayLength
000007fef840f000  4000097        c         System.Int32  1 instance               53 m_stringLength
000007fef84097d8  4000098       10          System.Char  1 instance               4f m_firstChar
000007fef8407d90  4000099       20        System.String  0   shared           static Empty
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004d32b0:00000000013d1308 <<
000007fef8409688  400009a       28        System.Char[]  0   shared           static WhitespaceChars
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004d32b0:00000000013d1a60 <<

EXCEPTION_MESSAGE:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

MANAGED_OBJECT_NAME:  System.NullReferenceException

CONTEXT:  000000002750b6b0 -- (.cxr 0x2750b6b0)
rax=0000000063aa0a1b rbx=0000000023ddb590 rcx=000000002750b6b0
rdx=00000000000000e0 rsi=000000002750bde0 rdi=0000000023ddb590
rip=000007fefd05965d rsp=000000002750bcc0 rbp=000000002750e340
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000038
r11=000000002750bd00 r12=00000000e0434f4d r13=ffffffff80131622
r14=0000000000000001 r15=0000000000000001
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000206
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x39:
000007fe`fd05965d 4881c4c8000000  add     rsp,0C8h
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 000007fef936b943 to 000007fefd05965d

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffffffffffff

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  CLR_EXCEPTION

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  CLR_EXCEPTION

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_CLR_EXCEPTION_NULL_INSTRUCTION_PTR_NULL_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`2750bcc0 000007fe`f936b943 : 00000000`23ddb590 00000000`23ddb590 00000000`2750bde0 00000000`23ddb590 : KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x39
00000000`2750bd90 000007fe`f9911cf0 : 00000000`041717c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : mscorwks!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+0x2ff
00000000`2750be80 000007fe`eded43f9 : 00000000`2750cab8 00000000`004db280 00000000`2750e2f0 000007fe`f94333da : mscorwks!JIT_Throw+0x130
00000000`2750c030 000007fe`f9425d0d : 000007fe`edc6fe2c 000007fe`ed5d1ec0 00000000`2750e2f0 000007fe`ed73bb10 : System_ni+0x9343f9
00000000`2750c0d0 000007fe`f943fe4a : 00000000`004db280 000007fe`eded43c0 00000000`2750e2f0 000007fe`ed73bb10 : mscorwks!ExceptionTracker::CallHandler+0x145
00000000`2750c1d0 000007fe`f93ac31b : 000007fe`edc6ffb2 00000000`770489fe 00000000`2750dcf0 00000000`00000000 : mscorwks!ExceptionTracker::CallCatchHandler+0x9e
00000000`2750c260 00000000`77048c3d : 00000000`2750df00 00000000`2750e2f0 00000000`2750c340 00000000`2750c3c0 : mscorwks!ProcessCLRException+0x2ab
00000000`2750c300 00000000`77037fdc : 00000000`27510000 00000000`2750ca00 00000000`0003c8dc 00000000`2750d658 : ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForUnwind+0xd
00000000`2750c330 000007fe`f932e48e : 00000000`2750e2f0 0000000b`aadbaad0 00000000`2750dcf0 00000000`23ddb590 : ntdll!RtlUnwindEx+0x539
00000000`2750c9d0 000007fe`f93ac2c7 : 000007fe`edc6ffb2 00000000`770489fe 00000000`2750dcf0 00000000`00000000 : mscorwks!ClrUnwindEx+0x36
00000000`2750cee0 00000000`77048bbd : 00000000`2750df70 00000000`2750e2f0 00000000`2750cfc0 00000000`2750d040 : mscorwks!ProcessCLRException+0x257
00000000`2750cf80 00000000`7703875f : 00000000`27510000 000007fe`ed8406f4 00000000`0003c8dc 00000000`004c5280 : ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xd
00000000`2750cfb0 00000000`77038d58 : 00000000`2750dcf0 00000000`2750d6c0 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x45a
00000000`2750d690 000007fe`fd05965d : 00000000`041717c0 00000000`2750ddf0 00000000`23ddb590 000007fe`f9407b7d : ntdll!RtlRaiseException+0x22f
00000000`2750dcd0 000007fe`f936b943 : 00000000`23ddb590 00000000`041717c0 00000000`2750ddf0 00000000`23ddb590 : KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x39
00000000`2750dda0 000007fe`f94aad4b : 00000000`041717c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : mscorwks!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+0x2ff
00000000`2750de90 000007fe`f96dfa95 : 00000000`067c57b8 ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`23d20ff0 00000000`00000000 : mscorwks!UnwindAndContinueRethrowHelperAfterCatch+0x63
00000000`2750def0 000007fe`f98bb2f3 : 00000000`23ddb590 00000000`2750e018 00000000`23ddb590 00000000`00000000 : mscorwks! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x7d605
00000000`2750df70 000007fe`edc75837 : 00000000`2750e1f8 00000000`2750e1f8 00000000`2750e2a8 000007fe`ed5d1e20 : mscorwks!StubHelpers::SafeHandleC2NHelper+0xf3
00000000`2750e150 000007fe`edc6ffb2 : 00000000`05a85f98 00000000`04171288 00000000`041713a0 00000000`0244a668 : System_ni+0x6d5837
00000000`2750e2f0 000007ff`001fc65f : 00000000`022420f0 00000000`01772650 00000000`01772650 000007ff`001fc7e1 : System_ni+0x6cffb2
00000000`2750e3c0 000007fe`edced58e : 00000000`0244a668 00000000`04171308 00000000`2750e6b8 00000000`2750e550 : 0x7ff`001fc65f
00000000`2750e430 000007fe`f82ddd38 : 00000000`2750e488 00000000`002a01cc 00000000`2750e5e8 00000000`2750e4a8 : System_ni+0x74d58e
00000000`2750e460 000007fe`f94cc6a2 : 00000000`016360d0 00000000`04171308 00000000`23ddb590 00000000`2750ebb8 : mscorlib_ni+0x30dd38
00000000`2750e520 000007fe`f938ff03 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`2750e840 00000000`00021212 00000000`00000000 : mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x82
00000000`2750e570 000007fe`f98aa291 : 00000000`2750e6a8 00000000`00000000 00000000`2750e8b8 00000000`00000008 : mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xd3
00000000`2750e610 000007fe`f93986d2 : ffffffff`00000006 000007fe`00000003 00000000`00000000 00000000`04970f78 : mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x2b1
00000000`2750e860 000007fe`f9929c12 : 00000000`04970f78 00000000`00000000 00000000`23ddb590 00000000`23ddb590 : mscorwks!ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper+0x12a
00000000`2750eaf0 000007fe`f82c2b82 : 000007fe`ed87c588 000007fe`f987edc5 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mscorwks!ReflectionInvocation::ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup+0x172
00000000`2750ed00 000007fe`edceebbf : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`744f3f69 : mscorlib_ni+0x2f2b82
00000000`2750ed50 000007fe`edced8ce : 00000000`01772650 000007fe`00000000 00000000`000000ac 00000000`00000000 : System_ni+0x74ebbf
00000000`2750ee90 000007fe`f82fa91e : 00000000`01772650 000007fe`fd05a662 00000000`000000ac 00000000`00000000 : System_ni+0x74d8ce
00000000`2750eee0 000007fe`f94cc6a2 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`000000ac 00000000`067c57b8 00000000`a1193ffe : mscorlib_ni+0x32a91e
00000000`2750ef30 000007fe`f938ff03 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000018 00000000`00000018 00000000`00000000 : mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x82
00000000`2750ef90 000007fe`f939004a : 00000000`2750f150 000007fe`f93cd6ab 00000000`00000000 000007fe`fd051935 : mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xd3
00000000`2750f030 000007fe`f9355503 : 00000000`23ddb590 000007fe`f93ce4ae 00000000`00001f80 000007fe`f93ccb8b : mscorwks!DispatchCallDebuggerWrapper+0x3e
00000000`2750f090 000007fe`f9898643 : 00000000`2750f3b0 00000000`067c57b8 00000000`000000ac 00000000`00000000 : mscorwks!DispatchCallNoEH+0x5f
00000000`2750f110 000007fe`f944d298 : 00000000`067c5768 000007fe`f9335840 00000000`00000000 000007fe`f93a9eee : mscorwks!BindIoCompletionCallBack_Worker+0xb3
00000000`2750f1d0 000007fe`f9360945 : 00000000`00000000 000007fe`fd0510ac 00000000`00000000 00000000`2750f350 : mscorwks!CNgenEntry::GetManifestFilePath+0x64
00000000`2750f220 000007fe`f932e52d : 00000000`00000000 00000000`23ddb590 00000000`2750f290 00000000`23ddb590 : mscorwks!SVR::gc_heap::make_heap_segment+0x155
00000000`2750f2f0 000007fe`f948a2b5 : 00000000`2750f350 ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`23ddb590 00000000`27508c50 : mscorwks!CAssemblyName::QueryInterface+0x95
00000000`2750f330 000007fe`f99b0bea : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00003a98 00000000`23ddb590 : mscorwks!ZapNibbleMap::GetSize+0x55
00000000`2750f390 000007fe`f99b1453 : ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`00000001 00000000`00003a98 00000000`00000001 : mscorwks!BindIoCompletionCallbackStubEx+0xca
00000000`2750f440 000007fe`f92ec132 : 00000002`00000000 00000000`1a1ad000 00000000`23ddb590 00000000`00000001 : mscorwks!BindIoCompletionCallbackStub+0x13
00000000`2750f470 000007fe`f9450134 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`000000ac 00000000`00000409 00000000`067c57b8 : mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::CompletionPortThreadStart+0x186
00000000`2750f510 00000000`76f159ed : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x78
00000000`2750fd60 00000000`7704b371 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`2750fd90 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  mscorwks!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+2ff

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: mscorwks

IMAGE_NAME:  mscorwks.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  53a11d6c

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0x2750b6b0 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  CLR_EXCEPTION_c0000005_mscorwks.dll!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly

BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_CLR_EXCEPTION_NULL_INSTRUCTION_PTR_NULL_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS_BAD_IP_mscorwks!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+2ff

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/VoiceInterfaceControllerBIB_exe/5_1_305_105/56b843fe/unknown/0_0_0_0/bbbbbbb4/c0000005/001fc6e1.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: `0xc0000005` is a 'native `NullReferenceException`'. Seems some native dep of `LumiSoft.Net.dll` is causing it.

Comment: Just a plain NRE.  If you take a dependency on a 3rd party component then you'd better have a support phone number you can call to get help when it bombs.